# Configure data source in spring and mapping in hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

Is it possible to configure to DataSource configuration in spring xml and keep the resource mapping in hibernate configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example in the Spring reference (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#orm-hibernate).